# Vary div height based on start-end points

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to make one vertical line what goes from start point (defined by

CSS) to end point (which I didn't define yet).

The idea is; **the user scrolls and the line keeps like sticky and/or grows its height** until the end point.

But I don't know which logic I should apply.

(Not-working) example: https://jsfiddle.net/uzegqn7f/

That line should go, for example, to the second image's top following the user's scroll position.

```
<div class="vertical-line line-1"></div>

<img src="https://dummyimage.com/900x300/000000/fff.jpg" alt="" class="line-1-start">

<div class="content"></div>

<img src="https://dummyimage.com/900x300/000000/fff.jpg" alt="" class="line-1-end">
```

---

```
.content {
    height:1000px;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.vertical-line {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ee403d;
    width: 4px;
    height: 10px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.line-1 {
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

---

```
var distance = $('.line-1-end').offset().top - $('.line-1-start').offset().top;

function line_animation(element,distance) {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        element.css("height", distance+"px");
    });
}

$(document).on('load resize', function() {
    var line1 = $(".line-1");
    line_animation(line1,distance);
});
```

**NOTE:**

- The distance between the elements is not always the same, may vary in responsive.

Comment: would this be closer ? https://jsfiddle.net/uzegqn7f/8/ line is drawn from a container holding both images . Not sure that i understand what this line is suppose to be boing stand there or appear at one point ?

Comment: The line should be drawn from the start to the bottom (from the first image to the second).

Comment: okay, so this border on the fiddle does the trick, or should it be some kind of anition or else? *(pseudo can be used to draw it over the images.  https://jsfiddle.net/uzegqn7f/9/ , it can also be partially hidden: on last image https://jsfiddle.net/uzegqn7f/10/  or both first & last https://jsfiddle.net/uzegqn7f/11/ or any https://jsfiddle.net/uzegqn7f/12/)*

Comment: Thanks for your time! The thing is the line should have animated height.

Comment: okay, css could do something like this. https://jsfiddle.net/uzegqn7f/14/ added extra margin below to simulate content behind and let image scroll up to top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (comments in code):

```js
var start = $('.line-1-start').offset().top,  // get where line starts
    end = $('.line-1-end').offset().top,      // get where line ends
    line = $('#line');

drawLine($(window).scrollTop()); // draw initial line

$(window).scroll(function(){
    drawLine($(this).scrollTop());  // draw line on scroll
});

$(document).on('resize', function() {      // reset top and bottom and redraw line on window resize
  start = $('.line-1-start').offset().top;
  end = $('.line-1-end').offset().top;
    drawLine($(window).scrollTop());
});

function drawLine(currentPosition) {
  if (currentPosition >= start && currentPosition <= end) {
    var distance = currentPosition - start;
    line.css("height", distance+"px");
  } else {
    line.css("height", 0);
  }
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzegqn7f/6/)

Comment: Quite close! I don't know if is about my viewport, but the line doesn't reach the other image.

Comment: some contents is needed behind so the last image can scroll upper :)

Comment: Okay, so I modified this example and worked as expected, so this will be the accepted answer, but thanks to everyone who helped <3

Comment: Sorry, went home after I posted this.  Glad you managed to get it sorted

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get to finish it but it's nearly there if it helps. It dynamically will figure out the height and start/end positions, you might be able to finish it off, it's not calculating the end position quite right, bit of tweaking and it'll be ok though. Checkout the JSfiddle;

https://jsfiddle.net/x4jhLohs/2/

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    handleVerticalLine();
  });

  function handleVerticalLine() {

    // Loop through and grab all our Vertical Line Containers, each one will have a Start and an End selector.
    $('.vertical-line-container').each(function() {

      // Grab our start and end elements.
      var $startElement = $( $( this ).data( 'line-start-selector' ) );
      var $endElement = $( $( this ).data( 'line-end-selector' ) );
      var $verticalLine = $( this ).find( $( '.vertical-line' ) );

      if( $startElement.length && $endElement.length && $verticalLine.length ) {


        var startElementTopOffsfet = $startElement.offset().top;
        var endElementTopOffsfet = $endElement.offset().top + $endElement.height();
        var startElementVerticalLineBegin = startElementTopOffsfet;
        var endElementVerticalLineBegin = endElementTopOffsfet;

        $verticalLine.css( 'top', startElementTopOffsfet + $startElement.height() );

        var verticalLinePercentage = startElementVerticalLineBegin / endElementVerticalLineBegin * 100;

                verticalLinePercentage += $(window).scrollTop();

        $verticalLine.css('height', verticalLinePercentage )

      }

    });

  }

});
```

Comment: The line doesn't reach the other image, may be viewport's issue?

Comment: some contents is needed behind so the last image can scroll upper :)

Comment: It wasn't intended to be a completed solution, but more as a good base to start upon